# Do I need to install a package to use Wayland on Cosmic?

Tags: xorg, gnome-shell, 18.10, wayland

I did a clean install of Cosmic, and I chose the minimal installation option, but I'd like to try Wayland. I don't seem to have that option available at login as most internet searches imply I should. Do I need to install a package to get that to show?

Comment: What is your graphics card and video driver?

Comment: Nvidia GTX 950, using nvidia-415 from a PPA.

Answer (score 3):

Simple [search on packages.ubuntu.com](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=cosmic&section=all&arch=amd64&keywords=wayland+session&searchon=names) gives the result - you need to install one package:

```
sudo apt install gnome-session-wayland
```

Comment: I have this package installed; no Wayland-related option shows in my login screen.

I have "Gnome on Xorg", "Ubuntu", and "Unity". The first two appear to do the same thing.

Comment: on ubuntu 19.04 after installing this package still no options at all in login screen, `$ echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE` still gives "X11"

Answer (score 1):

If using kubuntu 19.04, you need to install `plasma-workspace-wayland`.

From [ubuntu wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DiscoDingo/ReleaseNotes/Kubuntu#Plasma_Wayland_session_-_Can_be_installed_for_testing.2C_but_is_not_supported_for_19.04):

> Plasma Wayland session - Can be installed for testing, but is not supported for 19.04. A Plasma Wayland session can be made available for testing by installing the package plasma-workspace-wayland, however this is not supported. Users needing a stable desktop experience should select the normal 'Plasma' (without Wayland) option at login.

Comment: I'm not using Kubuntu, but this is a good tip!