# Second screen not detected

Tags: drivers, intel, external-monitor

I have a Dell Latitude 7400 with an integrated Intel UHD 620 Graphics and a dual-boot Windows 10 and Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS. When just running Ubuntu live from my flash drive, my second screen is regularly detected. Though, when using the installed version, the second screen is not detected (while in Windows it clearly is). Unfortunately, most solutions that I find online use Nvidia drivers, which I cannot use. Do you know what I can try? Please let me know which kind of information I should provide you with to try to figure out the issue. Thank you.

Comment: I have tried this solution, and I have indeed the options mentioned by Lypothirea. Though, if I try to choose Gnome, it automatically switches to Gnome on Xorg. And if I choose Ubuntu on Wayland, after entering the password, it brings me back to the login screen. I can login with the other two options (Gnome on Xorg, Ubuntu), then lock the screen and change option for logging in again. Then Ubuntu on Wayland accepts my password. But no screen is detected.

Comment: I see. Do you have any other idea?
(Anyway, for novel visitors to this question, we were referring to [this method](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1226223/screen-goes-black-after-vga-external-monitor-plugged-in)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it! Well, I did not do much myself. I installed Ubuntu version 20.04 LTS (which was released just a month ago), opting for a *normal* installation (as opposed to *minimal* installation) and toggling both other options (`Download updates` and `Install third-party software`). I don't know which part fixed it, but the second screen is now regularly detected.